# .Net Architecture: Implement asp.net identity as separate project inside solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a custom MVC 5 solution separated into 3 main projects, `Data`, `Admin`, and `Public`.
I need to add .NET Identity and it's related utilities.
I have read articles showing how to add it to an existing MVC project and I think I can handle that (basically add the dependencies/files).

My question is:

1. Does it make sense to add a `Security` project and put the related Identity stuff in there and reference from `Admin`/`Web` projects?
2. Or should it reside in the Data project since that's already referenced and handles the data?

Either way, how to implement Identity across the two sites? The Identity will be modified to include extra info about the user so it might make sense to be a part of the `Data` project...?

Also, how do I implement the identity/security project so i don't need to add Identity to each project? (Architecture is where I really need the help here)

Basically, how would I implement security as a separate project using asp.net Identity?

Answer (score 0):

When I build an app like this I typically am using Dependency Injection,  and have a project that defines my services call it Core (perhaps in your case Data?).  In this project I'll typically create a ISecurityService interface that defines methods needed to get the logged in user:

```
public interface ISecurityService {
  string GetCurrentUserName();
}
```

You might want to return more than a string, an object etc..  Then in when asp.net project that defines the functionality for ASP.net Identity I simply create an ASPNetSecurityService that implements ISecurityService and wire this into my IOC / Dependency Injection system.  That way any class that has a need to get this info Can just request a reference to ISecurityService and the IOC system will provide them the registered ASPNetSecurityService.

Alternatively you can use this same technique and place the ASP.net in a separate project if you wanted to, but by using this DI technique you can keep the Identity Stuff in asp.net mvc but still make use of the functionality from anywhere you like.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar this year and it works as I had anticipated. I have the ASP.Net Identity as a project of it's own. It has been customized as well for my company to handle all business logic/rules around authenticating users. I set it up as a NuGet package and can install it into any web project to handle authentication to a common user store. The consuming applications do not need to know any of the details about authentication. The developer just calls provided methods.

The way I started was I created a project from the default MVC template and made note of all the dependencies that identity needed. Then I included those dependencies in my custom NuGet package.

You can create your own NuGet packages using NuGet Package Explorer: https://npe.codeplex.com/

I checked my notes and here are all the dependencies the I wrote down (it's possible I overlooked one) that would need to be added to the NuGet Package:

- NuGet Packages:

  - ASP.Net Identity Core
  - ASP.Net Identity Owin
  - ASP.Net Identity EntityFramework
  - Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
  - Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
  - Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
  - Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount
  - Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter
- Add references:

  - System.Configuration
  - System.Web
  - System.Web.Helpers

Hope this helps!